# How to show $u=q$ for the following inner product

Tags: linear-algebra

$\langle u, v\rangle=\langle q,v \rangle$ where $u,q,v$ are elements of the inner product space, not fixed.
Does this imply $q=u$?

**Attempt:**
$\langle 0,v \rangle = 0$ *therefore* $\langle u,v \rangle = \langle q,v\rangle$ iff. $u=q$ since $\langle u-q,v \rangle =0$ implies $u-q=0$

**why my idea fails to complete the proof:**

$u-q$  can just be an orthogonal vector to $v$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. This question may make sense to you, but it makes no sense at all to me, and I've been learning/teaching linear algebra since the early 1970s. If you'd like folks to answer your question, you should click "edit" below your question and take the time to rewrite it clearly, in complete sentences, identifying one of them as the question you want answered (preferably through the use of a question-mark). Then you should add what you've tried so far, and where you got stuck; that way we can help you more effectively.

Comment: fixed took a while sorry

Comment: still doesn't make sense

Comment: please inform me if it still doesn't make sense, I'm trying my best to formulate my thought here

Comment: The statement $\langle u - q, v \rangle = 0$ implies that $u - q = 0$ is false, for the exact reason you stated: this only implies that $u - q$ is perpindicular to $v$. If your space has more than one dimension, or if $v = 0$, there are plenty of nonzero perpindicular vectors to $v$.

Comment: but if v is unfixed, does this not imply that u-q is perpindicular to every v in the inner product space, hence is zero

Comment: i guess what im trying to say, if i more clearly worded the fact that q,u are fixed while v alone is unfixed, this may have helped u to better understand my question

Comment: Rick: your first sentence is a fragment (there's no verb). The same goes for the first sentence of your attempt. The attempt's second sentence lacks punctuation, as does the very last sentence. Try again. Writing your question clearly may help you to answer it yourself, or to understand whatever answers you get. Either way, at least it shows a little more respect for the time of the people who might try to answer. (As of now, I am no longer one of those people, even though I now have a pretty good idea what your question might be, and its answer. You've driven me away. That's how it works.)

Answer (score 1):

Fix $u,q$. If $\left<u,v\right>=\left<q,v\right>$ for all $v$ in your inner product space, then you're good. We can prove this, as it implies that $\left<q-u,q-u\right>=0$ by multilinearity, hence $q-u=0$. Then we have $q=u.$ If $V$ is our inner product space, this property can also be used to those that the map $V\to V^*$ by $v\mapsto\left<v,\cdot\right>$ is a monomorphism.